# Awstats does not show all IPs from the Logfile

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server

I have installed AWstats on my debian server. 
Everything works great, but i dont see all of the entries, which are in the log file, on the awstats page.

My Config looks like this:

```
LogFile="/var/log/apache2/access.log"
```

The First entry of the Logfile is:

```
141.212.122.160 - - [01/Jan/2016:07:02:54 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 6634 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
```

This IP does never occur in the results of the awstats page.

I have deleted all earlier awstats file in /var/lib/awstats and updated them with the following commands:

```
# /usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=apache -update
# /usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=apache -output -staticlink > /var/www/awstats/index.html
```

I see some entries on the AWStats page. But definitley not all!

THis is the result of the update:

```
Create/Update database for config "/etc/awstats/awstats.conf" by AWStats version 7.2 (build 1.992)
From data in log file "/var/log/apache2/access.log"...
Phase 1 : First bypass old records, searching new record...
Searching new records from beginning of log file...
Phase 2 : Now process new records (Flush history on disk after 20000 hosts)...
Jumped lines in file: 0
Parsed lines in file: 456
 Found 0 dropped records,
 Found 0 comments,
 Found 0 blank records,
 Found 0 corrupted records,
 Found 0 old records,
 Found 456 new qualified records.
```

I Hope someone could help me.

Thank you.

Regards
Claudio

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the log format from 1 to 4:

```
#LogFormat=1
LogFormat=4
```

Comment: Can you explain what this change does?